# Shared folder path on aspx form

Tags: c#, hyperlink, directory, shared

I have some files in a shared location/folder. I need to provide a link/path on a webpage. If an user click on the link, user should be able to view the file.
I am using asp.net with C# (VS2010)

Is the above requirement is possible ?
If yes please help me in enabling this feature.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using something like `file://server/share/path/to/file.txt`. Firefox is a lot more tolerant of encoding of characters in filenames than IE, so you may need to use `Server.UrlEncode` on the file path.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to write an [ASHX Generic Handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) where you pass the requested file name as an URL parameter and that ASHX handler actually fetches the file for you, sends it to the browser.

This has these benefits in my opinion:

- It uses the HTTP protocol, not the FILE protocol.
- You are keeping internal structures internal, without exposing them to the visitors.
- You can implement access rights and other things since the files are streamed through your handler, and are not directly delivered by the web server (IIS).

If NTFS security permissions are an issue you might use impersonation for fetching the files from your shared folder location. I've written a [small impersonator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) class some years ago to simplify this task.